# React: Changing prop type value for nested component on page level

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm fairly new to `React` and what to understand how I can (if it's possible) change `prop` values for nested components at page level.

Here's an example of what I mean:

- I have a `component` called `Text`
- I have a `component` called `Image`
- I have a `component` called `TextImage`

In `TextImage`, I am using both `Text` and `Image` components. Both of these nested components have their own `props`.

Now, I cannot define these `prop` values in the `TextImage` component itself, because I may need to use the `TextImage` component multiple times on my page.

Here is `Text.js`:

```js
import React from 'react';

class Text extends React.Component{

  render() {

    const header = this.props.header;
    const copy = this.props.copy;

    return(
      <section className="text">
        <h2 className="text__header">{ header }</h2>
        <div className="text__copy">{ copy }</div>
      </section>
    )
  }

}

export default Text;
```

Here is `Image.js`:

```js
import React from 'react';

class Image extends React.Component{

  render() {

    const image_src = this.props.image_src;
    const image_alt = this.props.image_alt;

    return(
      <section className="image">
        <img loading="lazy" src={ image_src } alt={ image_alt } />
      </section>
    )
  }

}

export default Image;
```

And here is `TextImage.js` (in its current form):

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Text from '../Text/Text';
import Image from '../Image/Image';
import "./TextImage.scss";

class TextImage extends React.Component{

  render(){
    return(

      <section className="textImage">
        <Container>
          <Row>

            <Col md={6}>
              <Text />
            </Col>

            <Col md={6}>
              <Image/>
            </Col>

          </Row>
        </Container>
      </section>

    )
  }

}

export default TextImage;
```

I cannot do something like the below, because then those `props` will be consistent for whenever I use the `TextImage` component.

```js
<section className="textImage">
  <Container>
    <Row>

      <Col md={6}>
        <Text header="This is header" copy="this is copy" />
      </Col>

      <Col md={6}>
        <Image image_src="" image_alt="image" />
      </Col>

    </Row>
  </Container>
</section>
```

In my `Homepage.js` file, I have tried to do something like this:

`<TextImage header="test" />` which I kind of knew beforehand wouldn't work as the `props` are assigned to the `Text` and `Image` components within `TextImage`.

I can easily output my `TextImage` markup in `Homepage.js` (like below), but I'm looking for a cleaner approach.

```js
import React from "react";
import Text from "../components/Text/Text";
import Image from "../components/Image/Image";

function Homepage() {

  return (
    <>
      <section className="textImage">
        <Container>
          <Row>

            <Col md={6}>
              <Text header="This is header" copy="this is copy" />
            </Col>

            <Col md={6}>
              <Image image_src="" image_alt="image" />
            </Col>

          </Row>
        </Container>
      </section>

    </>
  );
}

export default Homepage;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass the  props which are used in Text and Image to TextImage component as below.

Demo at : https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-golick-zkmdi?file=/src/App.js

```js
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";

class Text extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const header = this.props.header;
    const copy = this.props.copy;

    return (
      <section className="text">
        <h2 className="text__header">{header}</h2>
        <div className="text__copy">{copy}</div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

class Image extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const image_src = this.props.image_src;
    const image_alt = this.props.image_alt;

    return (
      <section className="image">
        <img loading="lazy" src={image_src} alt={image_alt} />
      </section>
    );
  }
}

class TextImage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const image_src = this.props.image_src;
    const image_alt = this.props.image_alt;
    const header = this.props.header;
    const copy = this.props.copy;
    return (
      <section className="textImage">
        <div>
          <div>
            <div md={6}>
              <Text header={header} copy={copy} />
            </div>

            <div md={6}>
              <Image image_alt={image_alt} image_src={image_src} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TextImage header='Random Header' copy='RandomCopy' image_src='https://picsum.photos/200/300' image_alt='randomImage' />
      <TextImage header='Random Header2' copy='RandomCopy2' image_src='https://picsum.photos/300/300' image_alt='randomImage2' />

    </div>
  );
}
```